# printing variables with echo in a makefile

Tags: makefile, printf, echo

For airflow I wanted to run this:

`echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env` but this outputs in the env file: `-e AIRFLOW_UID=`

I was expecting something like:
`AIRFLOW_UID=1001`

I've read that echo -e has some quirks in makefiles so I tried `printf "AIRFLOW_UID=%s\n" $(id -u)`: Outside of the makefile it works as expected, but in the makefile it doesn't either.

Sorry if this is a duplicate there seems to be 1000 other answers but none of them really solves my question.

Comment: To not print `-e`, just remove it from the command. That's a `sh` quirk (a shell Make uses by default), not a `make` quirk. As for `$(id -u)`, you need to duplicate the dollar `$$`, otherwise Make thinks it's a Make variable access, and replaces it with an empty string there's there's no such variable.

Comment: Please show an actual example, including the full rule or variable assignment or whatever formatted as a code block.  Context is very important in makefiles and how you write things is different depending on where and how it's used.

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable.  It has nothing to do with make.  The standard for `echo` does not accept ANY options.  Some implementations of `echo` accept options, and some implementations of `echo` do not accept options.  In your situation `-e` is useless: I assume that you don't really want the output of your UID to contain backslash escape sequences.  So you can just remove it.  If you needed some special handling you need to use `printf` not `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @HolyBlackCat comment this has solved my issue:

`echo "AIRFLOW_UID=$$(id -u)" > .env`

which outputs in `.env`:
`AIRFLOW_UID=1001`